# Best way to reconnect SignalR?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

I'm trying connect to SignalR hub. All works, but I'm getting an error after the next login (Sleep mode).

Connection disconnected with error

```
Error: Server timeout elapsed without receiving a message from the server.

Failed to complete negotiation with the server: Error

Failed to start the connection: Error

POST https://localhost:*****/hubname/negotiate net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
```

How can I reconnect SignalR until connect?

```
var connected = false
this.hubConnection.start()
            .then(function () {
                connected = true
            }).catch(function () {
                setTimeout(function () { obj.hubConnection.start() }, 5000) 
            })

        this.hubConnection.onclose(function () {
            connected = false
            if (!connected)
                setTimeout(function () { obj.hubConnection.start() }, 5000)
        })
```

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: Did you implement the recommended error handling? onError => wait randomly between 0 and 5 seconds, then start connection again ?

Comment: I added the snippet.

Comment: Does the SignalR contain an embedded solution for reconnecting? Because I can to do something wrong.

Comment: Not that I am aware of, but I am _very_ rooky concerning SignalR. All examples I have seen explicitly do something like you did (if they happen to handle that case at all).

Comment: Does it because I working on my application locally?

Comment: It may have to do with sleep mode. I'd try to dispose and recreate the hubconnection instead of just restarting it. (But that's just a wild guess.)